# Is there a way to open a file in a shared folder using the file id(FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR) obtained from GetFileInformationByHandle()

Tags: c++, windows, shared, smb, filehandle

Currently, i'm using the following functions to open the file using its id.

```
volHandle = CreateFile(pVolName, ...);
fileHandle = OpenFileById(volHandle, &id, ...)
```

The id(FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR) is obtained from GetFinalPathNameByHandle().

This works for local files but when I tried it on a file in a shared folder(either from windows or unix machine), I get invalid volHandle.

Are there ways to open a file on a shared folder using its id(FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR)?

Comment: how you get id(FILE_ID_DESCRIPTOR) by call `GetFinalPathNameByHandle().` ? this api not return you *FileId*

Comment: @RbMm, sorry, wrong function pasted. I used GetFileInformationByHandle() to get the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation for OpenFileById](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365432(v=vs.85).aspx), emphasis mine:

> In Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012, this function is supported by the following technologies.
>
> Technology    Supported
>
> Server Message Block (SMB) 3.0 protocol - **No**

In other words, you can't open a file by ID number over the network, only on a local file system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :) 
I also saw that in the documentation. However, I was wondering if there are ways to work around it -- like similar/other functions.